# Condition for select statement using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table as shown below:

**Example**:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE testo
(
 namea VARCHAR(10),
 nameb VARCHAR(10),
 details VARCHAR(10)
)
```

With some records:

```
INSERT INTO testo VALUES('A','C','xyz');
INSERT INTO testo VALUES('A','B','oxo');
INSERT INTO testo VALUES('B','D','ner');
INSERT INTO testo VALUES('X','Y','tye');
INSERT INTO testo VALUES('Z','U','txt');
INSERT INTO testo VALUES('Y','N','str');

namea nameb details
-------------------
 A      C   xyz
 A      B   oxo
 B      D   ner
 X      Y   tye
 Z      U   txt
 Y      N   str
```

**Note**: I want to show those records where `nameb` exists in `namea` and also want to show that record where `namea` belongs to that `nameb` which is present in `namea`.

Expected Result:

```
namea  nameb  details
---------------------
 A      B       oxo
 B      D       ner
 X      Y       tye
 Y      N       str
```

For which I have tried:

```
 select * from testo
 where nameb in (select namea from testo);
```

But getting only:

```
namea  nameb  details
---------------------
 B      D       ner
 Y      N       str
```

SQL Fiddle:-> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a3bb2/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from testo
where 
    nameb in (select namea from testo)
    or namea in (select nameb from testo)
```

Comment: Oh! I was trying using `AND`. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
SELECT * FROM testo 
WHERE namea IN (SELECT nameb FROM testo) union SELECT * FROM testo 
WHERE nameb IN (SELECT namea FROM testo);